# react js localhost working but heroku not working for customer email sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

My Localhost500 working but heroku link not to send email and not to show any error =>this is heroku logs --tail message:

2022-05-18T10:43:47.325326+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=7cf77536-632c-4ac5-98e2-51581e723818 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=376ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T10:44:40.680794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=2eade93e-b6fb-4ee4-b1f1-77902b033b73 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=376ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T10:59:41.498704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting 2022-05-18T10:59:41.520899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting 2022-05-18T10:59:42.111370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 2022-05-18T10:59:42.341468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143 2022-05-18T10:59:44.054279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command npm start 2022-05-18T10:59:45.749250+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-18T10:59:45.749261+00:00 app[web.1]: > doctors-portal-server@1.0.0 start 2022-05-18T10:59:45.749261+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js 2022-05-18T10:59:45.749261+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-18T10:59:46.203340+00:00 app[web.1]: Doctors app listening on port 54112 2022-05-18T10:59:46.257941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up 2022-05-18T11:00:02.530314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=109507ed-1635-4dbd-a73e-893a73720055 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=387ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:00:05.043814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=2f27c09c-67a9-49f9-948c-c5e4d5b0f38b fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=374ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:00:07.725084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=18bdc39b-1132-4cf6-93ec-64f4983ec15a fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:00:08.034377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=a6e48f02-9c60-4a1d-8c43-d0ab42df1dd9 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:15:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user wabshahid@gmail.com 2022-05-18T11:16:20.165487+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d3f67e26 by user wabshahid@gmail.com 2022-05-18T11:16:20.165487+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user wabshahid@gmail.com 2022-05-18T11:16:20.425706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting 2022-05-18T11:16:20.439686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting 2022-05-18T11:16:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded 2022-05-18T11:16:21.141158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 2022-05-18T11:16:21.296685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143 2022-05-18T11:16:23.006032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command npm start 2022-05-18T11:16:24.768519+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-18T11:16:24.768529+00:00 app[web.1]: > doctors-portal-server@1.0.0 start 2022-05-18T11:16:24.768529+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js 2022-05-18T11:16:24.768530+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-05-18T11:16:25.164573+00:00 app[web.1]: Doctors app listening on port 32190 2022-05-18T11:16:25.279013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up 2022-05-18T11:16:26.326344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=348516c5-34ac-478f-bfe7-cfb72eb3326b fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=424 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:16:28.015051+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=3073312a-0ca7-4879-9b2c-81ef9647fa5e fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=387ms status=200 bytes=2506 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:16:30.555903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=d29c817e-4191-4885-bf7d-511425192cc3 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=381ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:16:37.454635+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=22214293-2796-454b-aa06-b037aeb987b3 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:16:37.747749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=cc833a59-212b-4a4e-b461-347eab237ff4 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:16:54.559647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=05da1cdc-1345-4129-a1ed-adcb36d5cafe fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=383ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:17:01.338332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=6b0011c2-4367-4f1e-8049-03528482924e fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=381ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:17:45.822793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=bc0c137a-380d-4a3a-8312-948050095846 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:17:59.192010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=e51f6fc0-b454-4e63-af9b-abe5e5fd2c38 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=381ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:17:59.597926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=df2a851a-e923-4f17-9414-10780671f76e fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:17:59.894621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=45a349d5-b8ca-450f-9b58-2c047fa1eb91 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:12.796151+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=478f8ccf-22fc-434a-b92e-474528fc701d fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:17.295401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=711d90d0-5a99-4989-b775-7e948112b5e4 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:17.595331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=00baae21-559f-41fc-a630-959b29df5548 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:17.602068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=45f72d54-82d6-44c3-8848-3fad0656b233 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:29.075155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=02f23e75-a0ba-4f02-bcf6-d194ce93a4ec fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=382ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:33.934887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=715e934d-17d0-455a-adc3-55d611eae202 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:19:40.856019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=cc46d75d-dab9-40f4-a1b5-d7aa19cf72f3 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:10.711628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=dee9f5a8-32ed-4475-8912-741b5d6b64d8 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:15.093858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=456cc584-b17e-4862-afef-2ef769dcb473 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:15.384672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=30a19b17-420c-4e65-a2a1-f73062efd034 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:15.419001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/%20booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=5c6cd372-5f7d-4e1b-afbd-76acbf416ff9 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:42.367526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=44f68d1e-c02a-418a-9a5b-cd78779b9b64 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:48.631398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=0699440c-5672-496a-960c-843eef7844c8 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=200 bytes=2484 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:20:50.787560+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=b50f27a1-f8c0-4c57-bbae-5e1b68297be8 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:27.936238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=636f0546-e7c0-402f-8877-e4eb415954f9 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:31.916768+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=c3af435c-04b7-4bbb-86b9-6b0f8547e496 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:35.847791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=ced3e4cd-5aec-498a-8857-778498d87315 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:36.688003+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=51c7b27b-1d27-4365-bc9d-1a91b993b561 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:42.051207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=a72a586d-ae54-4358-bfdb-124a1520aa43 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=200 bytes=2462 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:47.988900+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=6816d43c-57f1-40f3-8432-3cdc856d947e fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:23:52.172196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=13b62612-7ab3-493d-b01c-f66c81762273 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:25:52.602425+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=44928f13-913a-432f-a020-316a1762e9da fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=379ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:25:56.391634+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=ce467915-e981-4735-a575-142ede13d8aa fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:25:57.080697+00:00 app[web.1]: sending email 2022-05-18T11:25:57.080801+00:00 app[web.1]: shahidulislam1474@gmail.com 2022-05-18T11:25:57.088364+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=f957d1b9-2138-4421-bd12-1e269e4ba24f fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=400ms status=200 bytes=326 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239924+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239925+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/sendgrid/lib/sendgrid.js:88:25) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239926+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239928+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (node:events:527:28) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239929+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request. (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239929+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (node:events:527:28) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239930+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage. (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239930+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239931+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239931+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.239931+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) 2022-05-18T11:25:57.770253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=5b309fb7-be8d-4184-9269-167466d303d4 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=200 bytes=2440 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:26:14.061775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=c1da091a-95fa-459c-9be3-5135f6fc5786 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:26:19.068600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=5e34c455-f34f-4ee1-967c-ab9dd3f83401 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:26:19.776726+00:00 app[web.1]: sending email 2022-05-18T11:26:19.776803+00:00 app[web.1]: shahidulislam1474@gmail.com 2022-05-18T11:26:19.778514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/booking" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=79834e1e-8843-4684-8f62-85b95bb5936d fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=412ms status=200 bytes=326 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878142+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878143+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/sendgrid/lib/sendgrid.js:88:25) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878143+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878144+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (node:events:527:28) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878144+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request. (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878144+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (node:events:527:28) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878145+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage. (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878147+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878147+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878147+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12) 2022-05-18T11:26:19.878148+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) 2022-05-18T11:26:22.038030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=7e2075e1-c321-47f6-b778-da1102f102d9 fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=200 bytes=2418 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:26:40.843375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=e7530428-8656-4fb2-9664-592d4159b7fb fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https 2022-05-18T11:26:42.855845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/available?date=May%2018,%202022" host=polar-spire-82017.herokuapp.com request_id=c219d093-5d90-463d-b5a9-903e5b80685d fwd="59.153.17.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=304 bytes=183 protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

use procfile in main Directory and describe web : index.js in Procfile
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24GWj.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).